# How does matplotlib knows which Figure object to associate with which Axes object?

Tags: python, matplotlib, oop, visualization

I am currently learning matplotlib using a book named "python data science handbook". I found various instances where the OOP interface of matplotlib is used rather than matlab style interface.
Example:

> fig = plt.figure()
> ax = plt.axes()
> x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
> ax.plot(x, np.sin(x));

I want to know, ho does the fig object get associated with the ax object, we have not used any function that binds ax object with that specific fig object . But the program is still working.
If i could get an explanation or a link for the documentation, it would be a lot helpful. same types of questions has been previously asked but have not been properly answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matplotlib.pyplot` maintains a record of all existing figures, assigning to each figure a number (1, 2,...). It also keeps track which figure is currently active.

`plt.axes()` adds an axes object to the currently active figure. The first line of the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.6.0/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L958-L1053) of this function is `fig = gcf()` which gets this figure.

A newly created figure automatically becomes active, but you can make any existing figure active at any point using its number. For example, `plt.figure(2)` will make figure 2 active. You can get the numbers of all existing figures using `plt.get_fignums()`, and check the number of the currently active figure using `plt.gcf().number`.